# GridView not appearing on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, oledb

I am building a web form. I have one search field and a search button. I am connecting to MS Access database to retrieve and display the result on the grid view. But my grid view is not appearing on the web page.

Can anyone please help me to find out where I am wrong?

Here is my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Smita\\Desktop\\Project.accdb");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable() ;
    if (txtMerchant.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter DBAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DBAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from Test where Merchant ID like '" + txtMerchant.Text + "%'", con);
        DBAdapter.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you are wide open to SQL Injection attack. You should get into the habit of using [parametized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb738521(v=vs.100)) from the start.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the DataBind, binding method first after you assign the data source. 
Like that:

```
GridView1.Visible = true;
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Isn't his "dt" still blank, or does DBAdapter.Fill(dt) change it?

Comment: Yes, db adapter fills it with the data, but unless you bind it, nothing changes, this needs to be done explicitly

Comment: I added GridView1.DataBind(); But still the same the datagrid is not appearing. Any idea??

Comment: Hmm, the code seems fine, do you see that the datasource is filled properly with data when you debug? Try adding `GridView1.Visible = true;` before DataSource assignment, I will edit the answer below as well. Can you post your aspx content as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt; //Assigned a blank table.
```

"dt" Doesn't seem to point to anything.

Comment: As Jakub said above.